# Operation not permitted - OS

Tags: macos, permissions, operating-system, chmod

I type this is in the command line

```
chmod -R 777 ./platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml
```

but I get as a return that operation is not permitted. Why is this happening? Any ideas it can be fixed?

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: Can you give us the output of `stat ./platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml` and `whoami` (don't forget to replace your username with `<my username>` or sth.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-install android as a platform, should re-create any folders that had bad permissions

```
cordova platform remove android


cordova platform add android
```